# Function mocked with ReturnsAsync returns different value than it should

Tags: c#, moq

I use this static method to get a simple fake object, which just returns the specified value

```
class FakeUserOption
{
    public static TUserOption Get<TUserOption, TReturn>(string key, TReturn value) where TUserOption : class,  IUserOption
    {
  
        var mock = new Mock<TUserOption>();

        mock.Setup(x => x.GetValue(It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync(value);

        return mock.Object;
    }
}

interface IUserOption 
{
    Task<object> Value(Guid userId);
}
```

Here is how I use it.

```
    var fakeOption = FakeUserOption.Get<IExampleUserOption, bool>("someKey", true);
    var result = fakeOption.GetValue(new Guid()).Result;
```

This code should result in `result` beeing true, which it doesn't. It is always false. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You forgot to include `IUserOption` definition

Comment: This looks like a scenario where a simple concrete implementation (backed by a dictionary, for example) would be much more effective than a mock, in terms of effort needed to set things up.

Comment: How does `IExampleUserOption` relate to `IUserOption`?

Comment: Your code does not even compile. You have no `GetValue` method on the `IUserOption` interface. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)